# How to remove 'AxesImage' from the list?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, signal-processing, spectrogram

this is the output of a spectrogram calculated from the magnitude of three axis (x, y and z)

```
(array([[  1.52494154e+11,   1.52811638e+11,   1.52565040e+11, ...,
                  1.47778892e+11,   1.46781213e+11,   1.46678951e+11],
               [  7.69589176e+10,   7.73638333e+10,   7.76935891e+10, ...,
                  7.48498747e+10,   7.40088248e+10,   7.40343108e+10],
               [  6.32683585e+04,   1.58170271e+06,   6.11287648e+06, ...,
                  5.06690834e+05,   3.31360693e+05,   7.04757400e+05],
               ..., 
               [  7.79589127e+05,   8.09843763e+04,   2.52907491e+05, ...,
                  2.48520301e+05,   2.11734697e+05,   2.50917758e+05],
               [  9.41199946e+05,   4.98371406e+05,   1.29328139e+06, ...,
                  2.56729806e+05,   3.45253951e+05,   3.51932417e+05],
               [  4.36846676e+05,   1.24123764e+06,   9.20694394e+05, ...,
                  8.35807658e+04,   8.36986905e+05,   3.57807267e+04]]), array([   0.     ,    3.90625,    7.8125 ,   11.71875,   15.625  ,
                 19.53125,   23.4375 ,   27.34375,   31.25   ,   35.15625,
                 39.0625 ,   42.96875,   46.875  ,   50.78125,   54.6875 ,
                 58.59375,   62.5    ,   66.40625,   70.3125 ,   74.21875,
                 78.125  ,   82.03125,   85.9375 ,   89.84375,   93.75   ,
                 97.65625,  101.5625 ,  105.46875,  109.375  ,  113.28125,
                117.1875 ,  121.09375,  125.     ,  128.90625,  132.8125 ,
                136.71875,  140.625  ,  144.53125,  148.4375 ,  152.34375,
                156.25   ,  160.15625,  164.0625 ,  167.96875,  171.875  ,
                175.78125,  179.6875 ,  183.59375,  187.5    ,  191.40625,
                195.3125 ,  199.21875,  203.125  ,  207.03125,  210.9375 ,
                214.84375,  218.75   ,  222.65625,  226.5625 ,  230.46875,
                234.375  ,  238.28125,  242.1875 ,  246.09375,  250.     ,
                253.90625,  257.8125 ,  261.71875,  265.625  ,  269.53125,
                273.4375 ,  277.34375,  281.25   ,  285.15625,  289.0625 ,
                292.96875,  296.875  ,  300.78125,  304.6875 ,  308.59375,
                312.5    ,  316.40625,  320.3125 ,  324.21875,  328.125  ,
                332.03125,  335.9375 ,  339.84375,  343.75   ,  347.65625,
                351.5625 ,  355.46875,  359.375  ,  363.28125,  367.1875 ,
                371.09375,  375.     ,  378.90625,  382.8125 ,  386.71875,
                390.625  ,  394.53125,  398.4375 ,  402.34375,  406.25   ,
                410.15625,  414.0625 ,  417.96875,  421.875  ,  425.78125,
                429.6875 ,  433.59375,  437.5    ,  441.40625,  445.3125 ,
                449.21875,  453.125  ,  457.03125,  460.9375 ,  464.84375,
                468.75   ,  472.65625,  476.5625 ,  480.46875,  484.375  ,
                488.28125,  492.1875 ,  496.09375,  500.     ]), array([  1.28000000e-01,   2.56000000e-01,   3.84000000e-01, ...,
                 1.41529600e+03,   1.41542400e+03,   1.41555200e+03]), <matplotlib.image.AxesImage object at 0x000002161A78F898>)
```

the above data is stored also in a textfile but i cannot use it because of the last line 
)

this is what i have tried

```
dataset = np.loadtxt("trainingdatasetMAG.txt", delimiter=",")
X = dataset[:,0:6]
Y = dataset[:,6]
fake_size = 1415684
time = np.arange(fake_size)/1000 # 1kHz
base_freq = 2 * np.pi * 100
magnitude = dataset[:,5]
plt.figure()
plt.title('xyz_magnitude')
plt.axes('off')
ls=(plt.specgram(magnitude, Fs=1000))
```

Comment: `new = [x for x in org[:-1]]` will give you a new list minus last item were `org` is the variable name of your current "list" (which is really a tuple, so you would need to change ends from `[]` to `()` if you wanted another tuple.

Comment: Sure...lets start with what you have tried.

Comment: I dont think you understand. Show us what you've tried first, then we will help you.

Comment: Surely you have tried to debug or attempt a fix

Comment: thanks alot , i have tried the line of code you posted above and it works for me. thanks again for your effort